# Тип прокси при подключения к FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, proxy

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно жестко указать http тип подключения при работе с FTP серверов?

```
ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
ftp.Proxy = proxy;
ftp.Credentials = credential;
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
```

Вот мой код, необходимо что подключение к прокси происходило через http. Нашел вот такое - платную библиотеку Rebex, там можно при подключении указать `client.Proxy.ProxyType = FtpProxyType.HttpConnect;` как это можно сделать без сторонней библиотеки?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.proxy.aspx#Examples

Comment: @DigitalCore что я должен понять? Что http должно работать так как метод ListDirectoryDetails?

Comment: `FtpWebRequest Proxy`  будет работать только на порту 443 SSL

Comment: @DigitalCore какие у меня могут быть варианты? Посоветуйте пожалуйста. На прокси порт 8080.

Comment: `ftp.Proxy = new WebProxy();` учтите, что использованный прокси сервер должен поддерживать FTP протокол.

Comment: @DigitalCore а если только HTTP что делать? Неужели тупик.

Comment: Пишу с телефона, если никто не ответит, по приезду накидаю класс.

Comment: Я что-то не понял, что значит, подключение происходило через `http`, а через что оно происходит, через `Socks5`?

Comment: @DigitalCore спасибо буду ждать

Answer (score 3):

Нашел решение, подключил [это](https://winscp.net). Вот пример моего кода :

```
//Setup session options
sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = FTPUrl,
    UserName = FTPUser,
    Password = FTPPass,
};

// Configure proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3"); // 3 = HTTP proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", proxyHost);
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", proxyPort);

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.ExecutablePath = exFilePath;
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Download files
    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
    transferResult =
        session.GetFiles("/inbox/*", localPathInbox, false, transferOptions);

    // Throw on any error
    transferResult.Check();

    // Print results
    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Log.Write(null, transfer.FileName + " - файл загружен");
    }
}
```